# URL errors of URI submitted has disallowed characters

Tags: url, htaccess

In google webmaster tools i seem to be getting of 503 pages and other errors
The website is old.
Mainly from old url's that don't exist anymore.

For example
page.com/meubels?page=75&%24Version=1&%24Path=%2F 
=> returns *"Disallowed Key Characters."*

Another url error is the following: page.com/brands/brand%3Fpage=1?page=1 
=> returns *"The URI you submitted has disallowed characters."*

Related [Invalid Get Data](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5272/redirect-prevent-webmaster-tools-crawl-errors-using-htacces) was solved here.

Is it possible to have a 301 redirect to such url's through htaccess or any other way to redirect visitor's to the correct pages in staid of having them stuck on old url's with error pages.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what are you looking to answer?

Comment: Sorry that was a bit cryptic indeed, I clarified.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting the "disallowed characters" messages is that EE doesn't allow some characters (such as `%`) in URLs as a security measure.

You can certainly catch these before they get to EE using `.htaccess` - but how you'd go about redirecting is all dependent on how the old URLs relate to the new ones (what shared or identifying information they have).

If the URLs don't have any key shared info that will allow you to write a proper redirect pattern, you could aways collect every offending URL and put in a manual redirect for each:

```
Redirect /meubels?page=75&%24Version=1&%24Path=%2F http://page.com/meubels/the-new-page
```

Comment: Hi, I did try but it gives me "Internal Server Error" although redirecting to any other url like you said without special characters does work.